# How to import class from different script, where the class uses a global variable at initialization?

Tags: python

From one file, I'm trying to import and initialize a class from another file, where that class is initialized with a global variable defined in the calling file.

My file setup looks like this.

```
folder
├──subfolder
│   └──  __init__.py
│   └──  sub.py
├──__init__.py
├──orig.py
```

My `orig.py` file looks like this:

```
from folder.subfolder.sub import Test

def varinit():
    global var
    var = 8

def runn():
    varinit()
    testInstance = Test()
    testInstance.print_modvar()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    runn()
```

My `sub.py` file looks like this:

```
from folder.orig import var

class Test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.mod_var=var+8

    def print_modvar(self):

        print(self.mod_var)
```

In my terminal, I set:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/rootfolder
```

Where `rootfolder` contains folder.

When I run `python3 folder.orig.py` I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "folder/orig.py", line 1, in <module>
    from folder.subfolder.sub import Test
  File "/content/folder/subfolder/sub.py", line 1, in <module>
    from folder.orig import var
  File "/content/folder/orig.py", line 1, in <module>
    from folder.subfolder.sub import Test
ImportError: cannot import name 'Test'
```

The issue is that it is not able to locate `sub.py`? Or is it able to locate `sub.py`, but just not the class defined in `sub.py`?

How can I modify this to be able to correctly `import` the class, with it correctly using the global variable at initialization?

The result is that it should print the number `16`.

For convenience I have a colab notebook with the code that is interactive. The files likely won't persist though

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1mYk-XTpQh5d8IoTzXg9phGc2WupYKlRU?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uh you make some mistakes

the global variable declaration is not like this, the global modifier is used to declarate a variable is the variable in the global rather than declarate a new one(Disambiguation), instead of declarate a global variable

and i thinks that you cannot import one file that import back, it will into a cycle

so there a two solution(PS:I use a.py is orig.py and b.py is sub.py)

1. use the **var** as a parameter into the Test, like this

```
from subfolder.b import Test

var = 0


def varinit():
    global var
    var = 8


def runn():
    varinit()
    testInstance = Test(var)
    testInstance.print_modvar()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    runn()
```

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, var):
        self.mod_var = var + 8

    def print_modvar(self):
        print(self.mod_var)
```

2. use a config class to store the global variable

```
from subfolder.b import Test
from config import config


def varinit():
    config.var = 8


def runn():
    varinit()
    testInstance = Test()
    testInstance.print_modvar()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    runn()
```

```
from config import config


class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mod_var = config.var + 8

    def print_modvar(self):
        print(self.mod_var)
```

config.py

```
class config:
    var = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

`Var` is not reachable from sub.py. You are trying to import sub from orig, and orig from sub. That doesn't really work.

Instead you can move `varinit` to the sub file and use it from there.

orig.py:

```py
    from subfolder.sub import Test

    def runn():
        testInstance = Test()
        testInstance.print_modvar()


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        runn()
```

sub.py:

```py
    global var
    var = 8


    class Test():
        def __init__(self):
            self.mod_var = var + 8

        def print_modvar(self):
            print(self.mod_var)
```

output:

> 16

Comment: "Var is not reachable from sub.py. You are trying to import sub from orig, and orig from sub. That doesn't really work." Is this a case of 'circular imports?' moving var to the sub file doesn't work for the original problem this mineralized example is meant for, but it seems that the original code is flawed.